# Anything below froyo can't read method in 3rd party library

Tags: android

I'm using the jexcel api in my android application. It works great on devices running Android 2.2, but any other device just gives a blank String when I try to get the contents of a cell.

I've narrowed the thing thats not working to the Cell.getContents() method in the jexcel api. All android version below 2.2 are able to get the workbook, get the sheets, get the number of sheets, and they can get the cells, but when trying to get the contents within that cell, it return a blank string.

Is there something wrong with the library, or is it an android problem

Comment: are you testing it on the emulator or real device? any exceptions in the log reg. jexcel?

Comment: On a Real 2.2 device - it works great, i get 50 list items filled with text
On a 2.2 emulator - it works great, i get the same thing as on a real device
on 1.5-2.1 emulator - it gives me 50 blank list items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that FroYo added in support for some new Apache Harmony class or method (JavaSE-compatible) that JExcel depends on. In earlier versions, JExcel happens to catch the exception that's thrown and quietly fail. However, this is just a guess.

Since JExcel is open source, you could examine the source code to that method and see what turns up. Or, you could temporarily add the JExcel source code to your project (since I'm guessing you're using a JAR right now), and you'll probably get a compile-time error regarding the missing class or method.

This is all a guess, though.

Comment: I already tried to add the source code to my project, oddly enough, everything complied normally.

I tried going through the source code, but i did not find anything that would make this not work on platforms other than froyo.

Comment: im marking this post as the answer because you are probably correct in saying that Android 2.2 added/modified something that this library uses.